# AJAX problem in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

This  works in FF,safari,chrome and opera very well, but doesn't in IE.

The error code is 403

```
 var datau = "trends.php%3Frastgele%3D33";
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",    
    url: "loader.php?kk=1&page="+datau,     
    data: "",       
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        $('#content').empty();                  
        $('#content').html(html);
    },
         error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
         alert(xhr.status);
         alert(thrownError);
          } 
});
```

Comment: What's your full HTTP 403 error? [There are many 403 errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).

Comment: HTTP 403 means the server thinks the request is asking for something it shouldn't (forbidden). Could you post your server logs?

Comment: [error] [client 115.64.xx.xx] File does not exist: /home/sitename/public_html/403.shtml, referer: http://www.sitename.com/trends.php?rastgele=33

Also,

115.64.xx.xx - - [27/May/2011:18:18:32 -0500] "GET /loader.php?kk=1&page=trends.php%3Frastgele%3D33 HTTP/1.1" 403 9 "http://www.sitename.com/trends.php?rastgele=33" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"


Happens only in Internet Explorer

Comment: Does it help at all to use absolute URLs instead of relative ones?  PS--what happens if you navigate to `sitename.com/trends.php?rastgele=33` using Internet Explorer?

Comment: if you type sitename.com/trends.php?rastgele=3 , it works in IE but It doesn't work by jquery, I really need to call the page by jquery

Comment: Why do you put the query string in the URL instead of using the `data` argument as you are supposed to?

Comment: I tried that too but still getting the same error :/
this code is the latest one

Answer (score 0):

You should now pass GET variables by url.
The following is recommended (don't do urlencode):

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",    
    url: "loader.php",     
    data: {"kk": 1, "page": 'trends.php?rastgele=33'},       
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        $('#content').empty();                  
        $('#content').html(html);
    },
         error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
         alert(xhr.status);
         alert(thrownError);
          } 
});
```