# jQuery Ajax error message 403 forbidden from server (ASP.Net MVC application)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis, server

I have deployed an ASP.Net MVC application in a Windows based server. It functions as required and I am able to navigate to different pages as I need. But when I try to render part of a webpage making a JQuery ajax call to preview a table of data, there it fails to load (Only in the server, this was not an issue while debugging and running in visual studio). I am not able to preview the data that I am requesting from the server.

I tested in different browsers doubting it might be a cross-browser issue, but it's not.

The error message in IE console:

> The server received the request but refused to process it

The error message in Chrome console :

> Forbidden 403

Here are my ajax call and controller method that returns data and view that renders.

```html
$('#btnPreview').click(function () {
    var formData = new FormData();
 var files = $("#btnbrowse").get(0).files;
 if (files.length > 0) { formData.append("FileToPreview", files[0]); }
 $.ajax({
   url: '/ListMatch/GetXlFile',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'html',
   data: formData,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   success: function (result) {
   $('#record').html(result)
  $('._ExcelGrid').html(result);
     },
   error: function () {
    //alert('Click Called');
   }
    });
});
```

Here is the controller action method :

```
public ActionResult GetXlFile()
{
    if (Session["user"] != null)
    {
        List<ListMatchDetails> lstPreview = new List<ListMatchDetails>();

        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
        {
            var xlFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["FileToPreview"];
            HttpPostedFileBase filebase = new HttpPostedFileWrapper(xlFile);
            if (null != filebase && filebase.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                if (String.Compare(filebase.ContentType, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0)
                {
                    using (Stream stream = filebase.InputStream)
                    {
                        IExcelDataReader reader = null;

                        if (filebase.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
                        {
                            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
                        }
                        else if (filebase.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                        {
                            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                        }

                        reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                        DataSet dsResult = reader.AsDataSet();
                        DataTable dtResult = dsResult.Tables[0];
                        if (dtResult.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            long? l = null;
                            int iPageSize = AppHelper.GetPageSize() > dtResult.Rows.Count ? dtResult.Rows.Count : AppHelper.GetPageSize();
                            for (int i = 0; i < iPageSize; i++)
                            {
                                ListMatchDetails lmd = new ListMatchDetails();
                                lmd.GlobalId = (dtResult.Rows[i][0] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt64(dtResult.Rows[i][0]) : l;
                                lmd.Attask = (dtResult.Rows[i][1] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][1].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.FirstName = (dtResult.Rows[i][2] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][2].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.MiddleName = (dtResult.Rows[i][3] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][3].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.LastName = (dtResult.Rows[i][4] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][4].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.Suffix = (dtResult.Rows[i][5] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][5].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.Company = (dtResult.Rows[i][6] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][6].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.AddressLine1 = (dtResult.Rows[i][7] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][7].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.AddressLine2 = (dtResult.Rows[i][8] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][8].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.City = (dtResult.Rows[i][9] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][9].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.State = (dtResult.Rows[i][10] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][10].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.Zip = (dtResult.Rows[i][11] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][11].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.Country = (dtResult.Rows[i][12] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][12].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.NPI = (dtResult.Rows[i][13] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][13].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.ME = (dtResult.Rows[i][14] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][14].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.IMS = (dtResult.Rows[i][15] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][15].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.Specialty = (dtResult.Rows[i][16] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][16].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.Designation = (dtResult.Rows[i][17] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][17].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.JobTitle = (dtResult.Rows[i][18] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][18].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lmd.Email = (dtResult.Rows[i][19] != DBNull.Value) ? dtResult.Rows[i][19].ToString() : string.Empty;
                                lstPreview.Add(lmd);
                            }
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return PartialView("_ExcelGrid", lstPreview);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SignIn", "Login");
    }
}
```

And here is the view :

```
<div id="mainContainer" class="container">
    <div id="tableBoddy" class="panel panel-default pre-scrollable">
        <div id="record">
            @Html.Partial("_ExcelGrid", Model.ListMatchDetails)
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Please advise whether this is something to do with the configuration file or windows server IIS or any other problem. I would appreciate any possible solution.

Thanks

Comment: have you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945532/encountering-403-error-while-using-ajax-call-on-ie ?

Comment: why are you using: type: 'POST', ? Actually what you want to do is a get method, to recieve data from server.
when you click on `#btnPreview` it triggers the ajax call? have you put a break point in controller method ?
if the controller returns successfully, can you put a console log with returned response from server?

Comment: This is a post request since I am sending a file to the server to read and send data back reading the file. Since I get the error as server received the request, but refused to process, it must be able to reach the controller.

Comment: Yes, but I have the same issue in IE and chrome both.

Comment: @MeenakshiDash, what returns http errors is not your MVC application but IIS. It didn't happen while debugging cause you were running in a development server or IIS express. Request is not reaching controller due to permission issue.

Comment: Try using full url in your Ajax call, including protocol, ports, etc.

Comment: Can you suggest what permission issue it could be or what change do I need to do.

Comment: I can see you are sending formdata but cant see anything in recieving end public ActionResult GetXlFile() where is the model param which is recieving it?? public ActionResult GetXlFile(model formdata)

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files is carrying the file and that's how it's available in the controller.

Comment: @MeenakshiDash, before checking permissions you need to make sure that url is correct after deploying.That first slash is targeting server root which could be inaccurate if you have deployed web application in a virtual folder. That's why I've suggested earlier to try full url including protocol and all the stuff.

Comment: @derloopkat, Thanks for the solution, providing the full URL worked.

Comment: @MeenakshiDash, I asked you to try this because just wanted to confirm that "/ListMatch/GetXlFile" was the problem. The first slash means server root. My guess is, you deployed your webapplication into a virtual directory (let's say "MyWebApplication") but the url is pointing to the website root. If a full url worked then you may also try something like "/MyWebApplication/ListMatch/GetXlFile".